# How to change NS servers for domain CloudFlare?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

How to change NS servers for domain on CloudFlare?

Because some ip addresses are blocked in Russia...

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what you want to do?

Comment: each domain on CloudFlare have 2 NS servers, for example: bruce.ns.cloudflare.com
edna.ns.cloudflare.com
how to change the DNS to:

Comment: aida.ns.cloudflare.com
jeff.ns.cloudflare.com

Comment: you can target specific CF IP but you will lose a lot of CF features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of cloudflare says that this is not pussible. The only way to do something like this is to create a new cloudflare account and move the domain into the new one.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203491930-Can-I-change-my-Cloudflare-nameservers-or-IP-addresses-

I hope this helps.